# removing x values without y in a faceted geom_bar ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am faceting a bar plot in `ggplot2` but I want to remove the IDs with no `y` variable associated with them in a particular group. An example with representative data set (given below) is

```
    ID VAL GRP
1   1   2   1
2   2   4   2
3   3   6   3
4   4   8   4
5   5  10   1
6   6  12   2
7   7  14   3
8   8  16   4
9   9  18   1
10 10  20   2
11 11  22   3
12 12  24   4
```

Here is the complete code

```
    df <- structure(list(ID = 1:12, VAL = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 
    18, 20, 22, 24), GRP = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L)), .Names = c("ID", "VAL", "GRP"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -12L), class = "data.frame")

    ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(ID), y = VAL)) + 
      geom_bar(aes(fill = as.factor(GRP)), stat = "identity") + 
      facet_wrap(~as.factor(GRP))
```

Plot generated is given below, however I want a plot where each facet does NOT have the IDs not belonging to that particular group as the ordering of IDs does not mean anything, they are just identifiers.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `scales="free_x"` to your facet_wrap call.

Comment: Thanks! that works perfectly.